# iMacros: Wrong format of SET command (trying to change html with javascript on youtube)

Tags: imacros

I am busy with making a macro in iMacros, but the script won't work. 
The function of the script is to add autoplay=1 on a youtube video. I would need this macro to play youtube videos which don't automatically play on particular sites! 
Here's my code:

SET !VAR1 (\"var test = document.getElementsByTagName('object')[0].getAttribute('data');
var test2 = test.replace(autoplay=0, autoplay=1)
document.getElementById(myytplayer).data=test2
")

Help is really appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This cannot work. In order to execute JavaScript in iMacros you have to use URL command

```
URL GOTO=javascript:javascriptcode;
```

And even this is not 100% sure way of executing JS on the web page.